# Issue for In-App Purchase framework (Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, in-app-purchase

I am getting below error in my project while I am trying to build my project. I don't have In-App Purchase functionality for my project but it works when I turn on for in-app purchase in Capabilities section in target of the project.

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDStoreKit.o)
  "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
      l003 in GoogleSignIn(GIDStoreKit.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Please help what I need to update or remove from my project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `Enable BitCode = true` from `Build settings`

Project -> Build settings -> search "BitCode"

Comment: Restarting Xcode does not work mitul. Have you faced this previously in your project?

Comment: Add StoreKit.framework to your Target's Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Also double check that AddressBook.framework and SystemConfiguration.framework are also linked.

Comment: Add "libz.dylib" to framework from the target -> Build Phases tab -> Link Binaries With Libraries,